# Linked list pointer is confusing

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class SinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def __len__(self):
        size, temp = 0, self.head
        while temp:
            temp = temp.next
            size += 1
        return size

    def middle(self) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        temp, newList = self.head, ListNode('whatever lmao')
        current = newList
        size = len(self)
        for i in range(size):
            if i >= math.floor(size/2):
                current.next = temp 
                current = current.next
            temp = temp.next
        return newList.next
```

I just learned data structure recently, and I was trying to make a linked list, which has a middle function that return the middle value of a linked list.

I somehow manage to do it by looking some reference, but the code is kinda confusing, and I don't understand why it worked.

In the `middle` function, I declare a var `current` and assign a `listnode` class object `newList` into it. so logically, because it's a OOP, it should only copy the class into the `current` var right?

or is it actually became a pointer?

(but I don't think it's a pointer because I could return `current.next`). The most confusing part for me is that the `newList` should have no connection at all to `current`, and yet it formed a linked list, if it actually has connection to `current`, why the changes I made for `current` on the for loop doesn't affect `newList`?

what happen when I assign `listnode` to an anonymous variable?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I edited my answer, hope it helps and have fun reading "lmao".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first want to note that I'd probably have implemented this using something like:

```
    def middle(self):
        steps = len(self) // 2
        current = self.head
        for _ in range(steps):
            current = current.next

        return current
```

Here, you use truncating/floor division to divide the length of the list by 2, which you call `steps`.  This will be the number of hops you make from the head of the list.

Then you create a variable called `current` which is just your current position.  Sometimes this is a "walker" or "context" or "pointer", but the idea is all the same.  Initially the head, the for loop causes it to take `steps` hops down the list.

After the for loop, you just return the node.

---

This is a wild one.

First, we can rewrite your `middle` as:

```
    def middle2(self):
        temp = self.head
        newList = ListNode('whatever lmao')
        current = newList
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if i >= (len(self) // 2):
                current.next = temp 
                current = current.next
            temp = temp.next
        return newList.next
```

Nothing important has changed here.  `size` was "inlined" into the two places it was used, `math.floor` was replaced with truncating/floor division and the tuple-style initialization that you had on the first line was split into the first two lines in this version.

If you look closely you might notice that `temp` is manipulated similarly to how I use `current` in my version:

```
    def middle2(self):
        temp = self.head
        #newList = ListNode('whatever lmao')
        #current = newList
        for i in range(len(self)):
            #if i >= (len(self) // 2):
            #    current.next = temp 
            #    current = current.next
            temp = temp.next
        #return newList.next
```

(Hopefully, the syntax highlighting makes the comments fade away here, revealing the similarity I'm talking about).

So `temp` "walks" the list.  That makes sense.  But in this version the entire list is walked:

```
for i in range(len(self)):        # Your version
for _ in range(len(self) // 2):   # My version
```

So we need to understand that.

Also, you have this `newList` variable that you create with lmao and then don't seem to really use, except to return it, and somehow is still works?  That's confusing -- we need to understand that too.

And lastly, there's this `if i >= (len(self) // 2):` block that looks sort of like the `for` loop in my version with `len(self) // 2`, but my version only iterates over the "first" half of the range while your version enters the if branch on the *second* half of the range (once we're at/past the middle node).  So let's understand that too.

---

Here's what's going on.

First, you're creating `temp` and initializing it to the head (and will be using it to walk the list as I showed in my version).

Then, you're creating two variables and pointing them to the same thing:  both `newList` and `current` point to this newly created lmao ListNode.

Then you're walking the (entire) list with `temp`.

Eventually during this walk, you'll satisfy your `if` condition (in fact, it'll be when you are at the middle node).

At that point, you first:

- `current.next = temp`
  -- Up until this point, `current` has not been changed, so it still points to your LMAO node.  So this line sets your LMAO node's `.next` attribute to `temp` (which, remember, *for this iteration is the middle node*).
- `current = current.next`
  -- Here, you reassign `current`.  So `current` now points to `current.next` (which is just `temp`, your walker)

On subsequent iterations you advance `temp` as usual, and will enter your if block, but an important thing has changed.

- `current.next = temp`
  -- Since, on the previous iteration you reassigned `current`, it no longer points to your LMAO node.  In fact, you'll never touch your LMAO node again until you return from it.  So effectively, what this does is unimportant.  (In fact, it does nothing really.  It "walks" `current` alongside `temp`).

So really, the only iteration that matters is the first, so this could be rewritten as:

```
    def middle3(self):
        temp = self.head
        current = newList = ListNode('whatever lmao')
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if i == (len(self) // 2):   # Changed >= to ==
                current.next = temp 
                current = current.next
            temp = temp.next
        return newList.next
```

And then you might notice that we really don't need that second line inside the if-statement:

```
    def middle3(self):
        temp = self.head
        current = newList = ListNode('whatever lmao')
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if i == (len(self) // 2):
                current.next = temp
                # (Removed line here)
            temp = temp.next
        return newList.next
```

And then you might notice that we don't really use `current` or `newList` as a node, but instead only *really* use its .next, so we can combine the two names and eliminate the `.next` (see final note):

```
    def middle3(self):
        temp = self.head
        current = ListNode('whatever lmao')
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if i == (len(self) // 2):
                current = temp 

            temp = temp.next

        return current
```

We don't need that LMAO node now, we can use `None` (or not initialize it at all):

```
    def middle3(self):
        temp = self.head
        current = None   # removed LMAO node
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if i == (len(self) // 2):
                current = temp 

            temp = temp.next

        return current
```

Finally, lets rename current to something more accurate, `middle_node`:

```
    def middle3(self):
        temp = self.head
        middle_node = None   # now `middle_node`, was `current`
        for i in range(len(self)):
            if i == (len(self) // 2):
                middle_node = temp 

            temp = temp.next

        return middle_node
```

And now we're at a mostly familiar place.

`temp` walks the list, and when we get to the `len(self) // 2` (i.e. middle node) we keep a reference to it.  My version stops iterating here and returns it, your version saves the middle node as `middle_node` but continues to walk the list (importantly, without modifying `middle_node`).

---

Final note, it's important to understand what allowed this to happen: mutation (of mutable objects) vs (re)assignment.  This post is way too long already, but since both names `current` and `newList` pointed to the same thing, ***mutating*** one, "mutated the other" (in fact, there was only one object that was mutated -- only one object exists, it just had two ways to talk about it).

This *doesn't* hold with assignment.

**Mutation:**

```
a = b = [1,2]
a.append(3)    # Mutation
print(len(a))  # 3
print(len(b))  # 3
```

**Assignment:**

```
a = b = 5
a += 2    # Reassignment that might be mistaken for mutation
          # (ints are immutable)
print(a)  # 7
print(b)  # 5
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, you explained it really thoroughly! I really appreciate your help! I'll take my time to digest this